# I am filling a given volume with Lead shot. Which size will give maximum weight - Size 7 or size 12

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, weights, functional-strength

Hi am filling a loadable sledgehammer with lead shot. I am trying to see which size lead shot will give me the highest load. Will filling with smaller size give me higher load or a bigger size will give me higher load.

[Trying to fill with lead shot - Sledge hammer](http://www.strongergrip.com/sledgehammers/epic-sledge/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Smaller shot will provide greater weight for the same volume, assuming the same density. Within an infinite space, the difference is actually pretty negligible under optimum packing due to the way the spheres nest, but you [will lost more space around the edges](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/notices/201702/rnoti-p102.pdf) as the packing sphere's radius increases because there's no way to fit an extra sphere into the spaces at the end.

That said, I suspect the difference will be pretty negligible for you, so it's not terribly important to pick one size over another.